# Why do some website start with www and other with app

Tags: http, https, web-applications

I'm new to web development, why do some site start with www.url.com and other pages start with app.url.com. is there a difference? PS I do not want to end up learning out dated things.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called [sub domains](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/subdomain/)..

Comment: is it not a web app?

Comment: A sub domain can be a web app, But is also could be a api. Anything really